# Read Time Signature (like 4/4) from midi file IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, midi

Spent almost half a day and still can `t understand how I get the values ​​of 4 and 4  (4/4) from a midi file using iOS (objective c, CoreMIDI)

I have a midi file 4/4 19 bars 120 bmp

I tried following code:

```
MusicTimeStamp inBeats;
UInt32 inSubbeatDivisor;
CABarBeatTime outBarBeatTime;
MusicSequenceBeatsToBarBeatTime(aSequence, inBeats, inSubbeatDivisor, &outBarBeatTime);

NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %f", outBarBeatTime.bar, outBarBeatTime.beat, outBarBeatTime.reserved, outBarBeatTime.subbeat, outBarBeatTime.subbeatDivisor, inBeats);
```

NSLOG RESULT: 5, 3, 755, 0, 50617, 0.000000

Not sure what to do with this info from NSLog.

If the midi file will be 6/2 or 4/2 or 5/8. Then I want to simply get this values (second/first)

Can some one help me to calculate it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MusicSequenceBeatsToBarBeatTime` just converts a timestamp between two different formats, but it does not tell you what time signature it used for the conversion.

Time signatures are specified with a time signature meta event in the tempo track.
So you have to get the tempo track with [MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack), use a [MusicEventIterator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicEventIterator_Reference/Reference/reference.html) to search for the events with type `kMusicEventType_Meta`, and check if those events are time signature meta events (there might be multiple time signature events if the time signature changes).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for CL. user After small-scale experiments I did and get following:

Here we loading midi file:

```
+(void) openMidiFile: (NSString *) path{

    MusicSequence s;
    NewMusicSequence(&s);


    NSURL * midiFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    MusicSequenceFileLoad(s, (CFURLRef)midiFileURL, 0, 0);

    //Get tempo and time signature
    [self getSequenceTempo:s];
}
```

And here we getting needed info from tempo track.

```
+(MusicTrack) getSequenceTempo: (MusicSequence) aSequence{
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    MusicTrack tempoTrack;

    result = MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(aSequence, &tempoTrack);
    if (noErr != result) {
        NSLog(@"MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack, %d", (int)result);
    }

    // Create an interator
    MusicEventIterator iterator = NULL;
    NewMusicEventIterator(tempoTrack, &iterator);
    MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
    MusicEventType eventType = 0;

    const void *eventData = NULL;
    UInt32 eventDataSize = 0;

    Boolean hasNext = YES;

    // A variable to store note messages
    ExtendedTempoEvent * message;
    MIDIMetaEvent *metaEvent;

    // Iterate over events
    while (hasNext) {

        // See if there are any more events
        MusicEventIteratorHasNextEvent(iterator, &hasNext);

        // Copy the event data into the variables we prepaired earlier
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator, &timestamp, &eventType, &eventData, &eventDataSize);

        // Process Midi Note messages
        if(eventType==kMusicEventType_ExtendedTempo) {
            // Cast the midi event data as a midi note message
            message = (ExtendedTempoEvent*) eventData;
            // NSLog(@"%f", message->bpm); //TEMPO VALUE

        }
        if (eventType == kMusicEventType_Meta){
            metaEvent = (MIDIMetaEvent *) eventData;

            for (int i = 0; i < metaEvent->dataLength;i++){
                NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i, %i, %i", metaEvent->metaEventType, metaEvent->data[i], metaEvent->unused1, metaEvent->unused2, metaEvent->unused3);
            }
            NSLog(@"...");
        }

        MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator);
    }


    return tempoTrack;
}
```

The Result is:

```
**For 7/8:**
2014-09-17 14:03:14.073 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, **7**, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.075 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, **3**, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.077 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, 36, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.079 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, 8, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.080 MidiSequencer[1959:907] ...
2014-09-17 14:03:14.081 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, **7**, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.083 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, **3**, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.084 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, 36, 224, 215, 47
2014-09-17 14:03:14.086 MidiSequencer[1959:907] 88, 8, 224, 215, 47 


**For 7/4**
2014-09-17 13:59:45.455 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, **7**, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.457 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, **2**, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.459 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, 36, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.461 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, 8, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.462 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, **7**, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.464 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, **2**, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.465 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, 36, 32, 220, 47
2014-09-17 13:59:45.466 MidiSequencer[1922:907] 88, 8, 32, 220, 47
```

**So if we look to 7/4 example, here we have value:7 and value:2. Second value mean: 0 is 1; 1 is 2; 2 is 4; 3 is 8 and 4 is 16;**